# Any way to fix this type deduction?

Tags: c++, templates

Type deduction fails for the following case. It compiles if I specify the template argument to someFunc. I definitely see how this is a weird case but it would be nice if I could get it to work. Is there an alternate way to formulate it that would compile without providing the template parameter? A C++17 solution is fine.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using choose_arg_type = typename std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value,T,const T &>::type;

template<typename T>
T someFunc(choose_arg_type<T> arg)
{
    return arg + arg;
}

int main()
{
    auto result = someFunc(0.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not always use `const T&` ? as template/visible code, I expect compiler to pass argument the right way if not completly inlined.

Comment: I would assume the compiler can take care of this optimization for you.

Comment: @Jarod42 could be the fact that OP doesn't want to bind references to fundamental constexpr and ODR-use them?

Comment: The compiler may optimize when the code is inlined, but not in general, which would lead to decrease performance.

Comment: So - yes...this is about performance. The general wisdom I've read is that you have better performance passing fundamental types by value. One reason could be cache locality. But this simple test doesn't show any difference:

http://quick-bench.com/BXdkUX2YfBBnFg7m2gsOKo0dbkg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
template<typename T>
T someFunc(choose_arg_type<T> arg)
```

`T` is a dependent type.  Because of that no type deduction will happen here.  You can work around this issue by using [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) and introducing a set of overloads for when the type is fundamental or not.  That would look like

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental_v<T>, bool> = true>
T someFunc(T arg)
{
    return arg + arg;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental_v<T>, bool> = true>
T someFunc(const T& arg)
{
    return arg + arg;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - why bool instead of default `nullptr` for `enable_if_t`? Less typing :)

Comment: @SergeyA Yakk had said he ran into problems with that in some compilers but using `bool` and `true` worked.  I liked his suggestion as it reinforces that I want the condition of the `enable_if` to be true for this overload to be available.  I haven't actually seen a problem with `enable_if_t<...>* = nullptr` but  I've grown to like this way more.

Comment: I would be very interested to learn what would the problem be.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I know there is a known issue using `enable_if_t<...>* = 0` but I haven't seen anything about `enable_if_t<...>* = nullptr` being one.

Comment: @SergeyA default is `void`

Comment: `nullptr`->`void*` requires a conversion which is not strictly allowed in template IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

No, `choose_arg_type<T>` is in non-deduced context. There are quite a few duplicates already.

However, you can have two overloads, and SFINAE-enable them based on the type.